# create dynamic variable inside for loop to access array

Tags: javascript

I have multiple arrays which has same prefix name.

```
    var region1 = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07'];
    var region2 = ['08','09','11','12'];
    var region3 = ['13'];
    var region4 = ['14','22'];
    var region5 = ['10','15','16','17','18','19','20'];
    var region6 = ['21','23','24'];
    var region7 = ['25','26','27','28','29','30'];
    var region8 = ['31','33','36','37','38','39'];
    var region9 = ['32','34','35','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47'];
    var prefecture = "33";
```

Based on prefecture value I want to display regions

```
    if(region1.indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
        $('.region1').show();
        $('a.region1').addClass('regionSelect');
    }
    else if(region2.indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
        $('.region2').show();
        $('a.region2').addClass('regionSelect');
    }
    else if(region3.indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
        $('.region3').show();
        $('a.region3').addClass('regionSelect');
    }
    else if(region4.indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
        $('.region4').show();
        $('a.region4').addClass('regionSelect');
    }
    else if(region5.indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
        $('.region5').show();
        $('a.region5').addClass('regionSelect');
    }
    else if(region6.indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
        $('.region6').show();
        $('a.region6').addClass('regionSelect');
    }
    else if(region7.indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
        $('.region7').show();
        $('a.region7').addClass('regionSelect');
    }
    else if(region8.indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
        $('.region8').show();
        $('a.region8').addClass('regionSelect');
    }
```

which is working fine

But I am tried like this to minimize the code.

```
    for(var i=1; i<=9; i++){
        if('region'+i.indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
            $('.region'+i).show();
                $('.region'+i).addClass('regionSelect');
        }
    }
```

It says i.indexOf is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an array instead of variables.

```
var regions = [
 ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07'],
 ['08','09','11','12'],
 // and so on
]
```

then select by index

```
for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
    if(regions[i].indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
        $('.region'+(i+1)).show()
                          .addClass('regionSelect');
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP uses `.regionX` and `a.regionX` as selectors in the first example. They might not refer to the same elements.

Comment: @FelixKling: True. I based the selection off of the refactored example in the question where the `a` is excluded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. looks very clean and perfect

Answer (score 2):

I have seen so many questions on here where people try to use "dynamic variable" names when there are already other wonderful data structures such as the Array and Object available for serving this exact purpose.

```
var region = {
    "1": ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07'],
    "2": ['08','09','11','12'],
    "3": ['13'],
    /* snip */
};
```

---

```
for(var i=1; i<=9; i++){
    if(region[i].indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
        $('.region'+i).show();
            $('.region'+i).addClass('regionSelect');
    }
}
```

If you absolutely must use dynamic variable names, you can't do it with `var`.  You could do it if they were global (on `window`) and then access them via `window['region' + i]`.  I do not recommend this *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the object the variables are attached to using the `[]` syntax to refer to it's children, you can try with `window` if they are in the global scope...

```
for(var i=1; i<=9; i++){
    if(window['region'+i].indexOf(prefecture) != -1){
        $('.region'+i).show();
            $('.region'+i).addClass('regionSelect');
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I expect `this['region'+i].indexOf etc...` would work also

Answer (score -1):

Precedence problems.

You need to write

```
('region'+i).indexOf(prefecture)
```

otherwise it is understood as

```
'region'+(i.indexOf(prefecture))
```

As FelixKling notes below, this fixes the syntax error, but will not work, because you'd be looking for the prefecture inside the string `"region1"` etc. Check other answers to see how to really code this.

Comment: I can already tell you that this will always return `-1`, because the string `regionX` will never contain the value of `prefecture`.

Comment: @FelixKling: ... Doh. I was addressing the literal error, there's still the logical error behind it...